# How do I get an audio file sample rate using sox?

Tags: audio, sox

I would like to get the sample-rate of a given audio file using sox. Couldn't find the commandline to do that.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

just use:

```
soxi <filename>
```

or

```
sox --i <filename>
```

to produce output such as:

```
Input File     : 'final.flac'
Channels       : 4
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:11.48 = 506179 samples = 860.849 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 2.44M
Bit Rate       : 1.70M
Sample Encoding: 16-bit FLAC
Comment        : 'Comment=Processed by SoX'
```

The latter one is in case you're using the win32 version that doesn't include soxi, by default. To grab the sample rate only, just use:

```
soxi -r <filename>
```

or

```
sox --i -r <filename>
```

which will return the sample rate alone.

Comment: You know how you would ask JUST for the bit rate in such a way that the output could be read by a PHP script? For instance, it would just return "44100" instead of Sample Rate    : 44100

Comment: I made an edit, but in case it doesn't get approved, to get the sample rate alone, you can use:

`soxi -r <filename>`

which will show `16000` alone. Also, in case you're using the win32 version, which doesn't include `soxi` by default, you can just use:

`soxi --i <filename>` or `soxi --i -r <filename>`

The first shows the formatted metadata, while the second shows the sample rate alone.

Comment: Note that this `sox` program isn't included in OSX. You can install it with `brew install sox` if you use homebrew.

Comment: How to check the sample rate spectrum using sox